# Don't stop event propagation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

There is a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/post-form">
   <button ng-click="handler($event)" type="submit"> Button </button>
```

Without `ng-click` the form is submitted normally.

With `ng-click` the handler is called, but the form is not submitted.

Can I please have both?

Comment: worst case can use event target to traverse up to form and do form.submit(). SHow your handler code

Comment: The handler code is irrelevant.  Let's say it's `console.log('hi')`.

Comment: i would use ng-submit to do whatever you are doing in button click handler. Then no propagation issues

Comment: `ng-submit` will prevent posting the form, and, I need to watch for clicks on specific buttons.

Comment: no, read the docs, it doesn't prevent submit when action is included. If that's not what you want then use native javascript `submit()` to submit the form from inside your handler